# Is it safe to have a column of ID be just an integer (auto-increment)?

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

I have a table which consist of an id (unique) and information such as name, email, role etc. I am planning to make my id just be an auto-incremented integer. That ID will be put in a session and be used to gain certain access and query certain things that are related to said IDs. Is it safe to do so or should i make my id be something more random?

My concern is that someone can mess with the session and change the ID (since the ID is an auto-incremented integer, it would be easy to temper with) and have access to other peoples data. Is that even possible?

Comment: You should also have mechanisms for access control.  An auto-incremented id is not such a mechanism.

Comment: I have a role column in my table to implement RBAC model. What I am asking is if it is safe to do what i said, with the concern that i have on the last paragraph in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the ID as an UUID - universal unique identifier. Many databases support it and you can generate it using standard Java library as well. It is a string not a number and random enough to be difficult to be guessed. Later on if you ever need to merge 2 tables, schema you won't see any conflict.

The only downside to this is the index will little less efficient because it is a big string, but I will pick it because of other benefits.